# Sending a confirmation email without creating a model/controller and use of a db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailer

I've created a single page landing site which contains a simple waitlist form that dumps the info into a google doc (trying to keep it low tech for now, since an app will be built on top of this as well).

I'm trying to send the people who submit their email address for the waiting list a confirmation email. Can I pass the email address to a mailer without creating a model/controller and use of a db?

I've done this before by creating a model/controller (see below code) and use of a db (postgreSQL / Heroku), but it seems messy for such a simple task.

Here's my setup in the past, looking to get rid of the model/controller and pass the email address (w/ .downcase transformation) to the mailer directly.

models/waitlist.rb

```
class WaitList < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
 attr_accessible :email

 validates :email, :presence => true, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i }

end
```

controllers/waitlist_controller.rb

```
class WaitlistsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @waitlist = Waitlist.new(params[:waitlist])

  if @waitlist.save
   # Tell the ProspectMailer to send an email to us
   WaitlistMailer.waitlist_email(@waitlist).deliver
  end

 end

 private
end
```

mailer/waitlist.rb

```
class Waitlist < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "hello@domain.com"

 def waitlist_email(waitlist)
  @waitlist = waitlist
  mail( :to => @waitlist.email,
:subject => 'Thanks for signing up!' )
 end
end
```

views/waitlist/waitlist_email.html.erb

```
Email text (possibly HTML) for the body of the email sent via the mailer
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller *should* tell the Mailer to send the email.

In your controller `create` action, why not just pass the `email` param to your mailer?

**app/controllers/wait_lists_controller.rb**

```
class WaitListsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    send_wait_list_email(params[:wait_list][:email])
  end

  private

  def send_wait_list_email(email)
    WaitListMailer.wait_list_email(email).deliver
  end
end
```

**app/mailers/wait_list_mailer.rb**

```
class WaitListMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def wait_list_email(email)
    mail(to: email, subject: "Thanks for signing up!")
  end
end
```

**app/views/wait_lists/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(:wait_list, url: wait_lists_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
  <%= f.submit "Join" %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to do validation on the email, I'd recommend keeping your `WaitList` model and including `ActiveModel::Model` — not all models have to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`, only when they need it.

**app/models/wait_list.rb**

```
class WaitList
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_reader :email

  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
    post_initialize
  end

  validates(
    :email, 
    presence: true, 
    format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i }
  )

  private

  def post_initialize
    if email
      email.downcase!
    end
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/wait_lists_controller.rb**

```
class WaitListsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @wait_list = WaitList.new
  end

  def create
    @wait_list = WaitList.new(wait_list_params)
    if @wait_list.valid?
      send_wait_list_email(@wait_list)
      # redirect somewhere
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def send_wait_list_email(wait_list)
    WaitListMailer.wait_list_email(wait_list).deliver
  end

  def wait_list_params
    params.require(:wait_list).permit(:email)
  end
end
```

**app/views/wait_lists/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@wait_list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email" %>
  <%= f.submit "Join" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#calling-the-mailer

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html